# Qt - INFO with button hover with mouse

Tags: c++, qt, hover, mouse, info

**Qt** - HELP with button **hover** with **mouse**.

I want make something like **INFO BOX** about button, when user will **hover it** with **mouse** (hover like in **HTML/CSS**).

Something like this in **Qt Creator** when we **HOVER** some **reference**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `QWidget::setToolTip(const QString&)`, i.e.

```
QToolButton* button = new QToolButton(this);
button->setToopTip("Button");
```